# How can I get Ubuntu working on my G4 Powerbook 1ghz 17"

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, mac

Completely new to Linux but very keen to get it working on my [G4 Powerbook 1Ghz 17](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powerbook_g4/specs/powerbook_g4_1.0_17.html)

Have tried install of MintPPC 11 which failed to boot xorg and gave error:

```
[drm] failed to open device
Fatal server error: no screens found
```

Have also tried install of Ubuntu 14.04 from netboot, and that gives a black screen at boot, sometimes also offers a repeating message:

```
[   55.504281] nouveau E[     DRM] DDC responded, but no EDID for TV-1
```

I have tried various Xorg files, but not found anything to work.

Has anyone out there successfully installed to a 1Ghz 17" G4 Powerbook?

Answer (score -1):

well i had the same problem did may research and her it gos 
link for Ubuntu that works with G4 Powerbook 1ghz 17
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.4/release/
download the Ubuntu 12.04 PowerPC

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Will try 12.04.4. Managed to get MintPPC 11 running this morning - graphics card driver was pointing to nouveau rather than nv. Edited xorg.conf and away it went!